# jquery .attr() not working in IE7. Any work around to get the class of the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having this code to check if the element has the certain class:

```
var p3div = $("#portlet1 #showhide");
            if (p3div.attr('class').indexOf('ui-icon-plusthick') > 0) {
                //do something here.
            }
```

However in IE7 .attr() is not supported and this code will throw an error. Is there any other way to get the class of an element by not using the attr() method?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if($('#showhide').hasClass('ui-icon-plusthick')){
     // do something
}
```

1. No need to use anything other than jQuery's native `hasClass()` function.
2. No need to select elements which have an id with the descendants way, like `#portlet #showhide`, this will be way slower.

Comment: hasClass will always return false in my case using IE7 but will return true on firefox.

Comment: @mcxiand: Can you create a test case on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)? I don't think IE7 will differ from Firefox, because that's a thing jQuery takes pride on, cross-browser functionality, UNLESS you have some kind of plugin or anything which strips the class 'ui-icon-plusthick' from your DOM. Try checking the source, is the class there?

Comment: My bad Shef, i expected the class to be there however there is something wrong in another code again in IE7 that toggles a div switching classes. FF is OK so i thought its not working in IE7. Thanks a lot.